# find_packages() not detecting files for python egg

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a python egg file. My purpose is to bundle files in two locations. But it is bundling the files from only one location.
So I have written the setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = 'sample',
    version = '1.0.0',
    namespace_packages=['com'],
    packages = find_packages(),
    description = 'sample code',
    author = 'XYZ',
)
```

The setup.py file is in the location

```
/root/sandy/python/sample/setup.py
```

the com package is in the location

```
/root/sandy/sandy/com/sample.py
```

I have `__init__.py` files in the following directories

```
/root/sandy/sandy/__init__.py
/root/sandy/sandy/com/__init__.py
```

In the egg command I have specified the target directory a different location than `/root/sandy/python/sample/setup.py` because I have to bundle files in some other directory. I see it is detecting the setup.py file correctly but not bundling the files from `/root/sandy/sandy/com/`

How can i specify to pick files from multiple locations for creating the egg?

Comment: More than a day. No replies :-(